# sqlite3 C API querying for a title concat

Tags: c, sqlite

in sqlite3 using the command line, if I want to enter something very approximate and get the correct output I use

```
  select * from <table_name> where <col_name> like '%<query>%';
```

where  is the name of my table,  is the column name and  is the partial query name for example

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE supplier_name like '%bob%';
```

as suggested [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

I'm using sqlite3 with C, and I don't know how to insert the "%" symbols at the starting and ending. Can someone suggest a very easy method to do this, probably with the use of sqlite3_mprintf for creating the sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *result = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE '%%%q%%';", "suppliers", "supplier_name", "bob");
```